# Questions tab: should the ordering by votes consider also the average votes on the answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, sorting

Since *questions are merely the sand that produces the pearl* and the trend is to *optimize by pearls and not sand*, should the sorting by Votes on [Questions on the main page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes) reflect this ?

*The facts:*

1. Questions [are not voted](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/05/vote-for-this-question-or-the-kitten-gets-it/)
2. [Answers are the real value](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/) of SE

Should the order by votes on the Question tab, consider not just the votes on the questions but also the average votes of the relative answers?

Comment: @slugster - I don't think this is for viewing *answers* on a particular question but for viewing *questions* on the main page http://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=votes

Comment: @Chris - yep i misread it. I like it even less now.

Answer (score 1):

Is the Question tab there to:

- Find questions to answer (that are well writen)
- Find questions/answers that are worth reading

Once we know, then we can decide how it is sorted.